# Can anyone explain why abs(10) % 100 = 10?

Tags: python, modulus

I'm doing some practice tasks for school and theres one simple one to make a program that returns the last two digits of any integer over 9. I found the solution online and it uses 'abs()' which I haven't seen before. somehow it made 10 % 100 = 10 which I don't get when, to my understanding, abs(10) is literally just 10.

```
a = int(input())

print(abs(a) % 100)
```

Comment: Absolute value of 10 is 10. And 10 % (anthing > 10) = 10. It's how the modulo operator works. 10 divided by 100 = zero with a remainder of 10. 10 % 11 = 10. 10 % 10000 = 10.

Comment: `abs` returns the absolute value of its argument. So `abs(10) == abs(-10)` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: `%` is not division, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: The abs is just there for negative numbers, it is the % that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator `%` can be understood as "outputs the remainder after integer division".

Consider `232 % 100 = 32`. After dividing by 100, you're left with 32. In other words, `232 = 100*2 + 32`. Integer division gets you the `2`, modulo gets you the `32`.

Consider `32 % 100 = 32`. 32 isn't divisible by 100, so the remainder is 32. In other words, `32 = 100*0 + 32`. Integer division gets you the `0`, modulo gets you the `32`.

Since `abs(10) = 10`, and `10 % 100 = 10`, then `abs(10) % 100 = 10`.

Answer (score 0):

The `abs` operator is the absolute operator. This means that positive values stay positive, while negative values will become positive values. For example:

```
    abs(10) = 10
    abs(-10) = 10
    abs(0) = 0
```

The percentage sign is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). This means that the answer is the remainder after division. For example:

```
10 % 10 = 0 (as 10 can be divided by 10 without remainder)
10 % 5 = 0 (as 10 can be divided by 5 without remainder)
10 % 11 = 10 (as 10 cannot be divided by 11)
```

Therefore, `10 % 100` must be 10 and, thus, also `abs(10) % 100` must be 10.